# Stuck with 2D Array

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a program that reads a text file (fine with this) that contains a list of doubles like this:

```
1.0, 2.0, 3.0
4.0, 5.0, 6.0
7.0, 8.0, 9.0
```

_

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("tstc.txt"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Program aborted.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    double[][] arrayNums = new double[3][3];

    for(int sec = 0; sec < 3; sec++) {
        while(inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = inputStream.nextLine();
            String[] lineList = line.split(", ");
            int pos = 0;

            for(int motor = 0; motor < 3; motor++) {
                double lineDouble = Double.parseDouble(lineList[pos]);
                arrayNums[motor][sec] = lineDouble;
                pos+=1;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayNums));
```

This is what I'm going for:

```
    [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]
```

But this is what I am getting:

```
[[7.0, 0.0, 0.0], [8.0, 0.0, 0.0], [9.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

I see already that my problem lies with the **sec** variable remaining the same, but I'm not sure how I can rearrange the code without having to change the whole code structure.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do not need the sec loop because You already have the InputStream one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work like expected.

```
    int pos = 0;
    while(inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inputStream.nextLine();
        String[] lineList = line.split(", ");

        for(int motor = 0; motor < 3; motor++) {
            double lineDouble = Double.parseDouble(lineList[motor]);
            arrayNums[pos][motor] = lineDouble;

        }
        pos++;
    }
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayNums));
```

Do not Forget to delete the first loop.

Comment: First off, thank you so much for your help! The problem is that in truth, the text file I will be reading from will have hundreds of columns (lines to read). That's why I was really trying to structure arrayNums likes this: arrayNums[motor][pos]. To save memory as well being more practical and easy to navigate.

[motor] is actually supposed to represent a car, whereas [pos] represents velocity. Each line in the file is a subsequent second stating the speeds of the cars.

Is there anyway to accommodate for this? Sorry for not being clearer before.

Comment: @AndréFoote If I understand it well enough, you should just change your variables names. But if you have another question, do not hesitate to create a new one since this one is already answered and it will get more attention from other users aswell.

Answer (score 1):

```
int sec = 0;
while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = inputStream.nextLine();
    String[] lineList = line.split(", ");

    for (int i = 0; i < lineList.length; i++) {
        arrayNums[sec][i] = Double.parseDouble(lineList[i]);
    }

    sec++;
}
```

That said if you didn't anticipate the number of lines in your file (i.e. there are more lines in the file than there are rows in your array), an exception will be thrown in the inner `for` loop

Comment: First off, thank you so much for your help! The problem is that in truth, the text file I will be reading from will have hundreds of columns (lines to read). That's why I was really trying to structure arrayNums likes this: arrayNums[i][sec]. To save memory as well being more practical and easy to navigate.

[i] is actually supposed to represent a car, whereas [sec] represents velocity. Each line in the file is a subsequent second stating the speeds of the cars.

Is there anyway to accommodate for this? Sorry for not being clearer before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the while-loop.

This would give you the expected result: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadMatrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileName = "tstc.txt";
        int nRow = 3;
        int nCol = 3;
        double[][] arrayNums = new double[nRow][nCol];

        try (Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileName))) {

            for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++) {
                String line = inputStream.nextLine();
                String[] lineList = line.split(", ");

                for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++) {
                    double lineDouble = Double.parseDouble(lineList[j]);
                    arrayNums[i][j] = lineDouble;
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Program aborted.");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayNums));
    }
}
```